# Set +x executable permission on a CD-ROM

Tags: permissions, data-cd

I want to add +x permission executable on my ISO. So I can run it directly on Linux host when clicking my CD-ROM.

I tried `sudo chmod 555 tester` and then burned it on ISO, but the tester only had read permission on ISO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by Vlastimil, the ISO 9660 file system is fairly limited, and several extensions were developed to overcome its shortcomings.  E.g. *Joliet* adds support for Unicode filenames, *El Torito* allows for bootable CD-ROMs and *Rock Ridge* enables you to use Unix file permissions on the files.

To be able to use Unix permissions on the CD-ROM files you need to add the Rock Ridge extensions when *creating* the disk's image.  You need to check the settings for the software you are using to build the disk's filesystem, to indicate you want to add this extension (incidentally, you are likely to also find options for adding the Joliet extension for Unicode filenames, or for creating a bootable disk with El Torito).

I'm not a Linux user, but a quick search on [`mkisofs`'s `man`page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs) shows that  this can be done by using the `-R` or `-r` switch (they're not equivalent, check the `man` page).  Of course, the extension(s) must also be supported by the `mount` command, but this should be the case for any modern OS.

You ask specifically about CD-ROMs, but for completeness sake, I'll just add that DVDs are usually authored using the UDF file system, which has native support for Unix permissions.

Comment: For existing images, one can use mount options to change the permissions on (all) files in the mountpoint. You of course cannot set this for other users, but if it is for your own use it may be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

34 years ago the [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) was introduced as a file system for CD-ROMs.

It has been improved in various aspects, like Unicode since then called Joliet.

But I believe it still cannot retain Linux file permission bits, did not find a proof of it fast but we can safely assume it.

As a work-around you could run e.g. `bash tester` instead, if it is a shell script. Have currently no idea how to run a compiled file. You could `tar` it for example, then uncompress it and run it.